# Arduino UDP Error WiFiUdp.cpp

Tags: c++, c, arduino, arduino-ide

I got the UDP into my library and included it in my sketch. I am getting errors still but different ones and it has to do with my cpp file. here is the errors i am getting. Does anyone have an idea how to solve these? You help is most appreciated. Do I need to open my notepad++ and include something?

```
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\WiFiUdp.cpp: In member function 'virtual uint8_t WiFiUDP::begin(uint16_t)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\WiFiUdp.cpp:25: error: 'UDP_MODE' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\WiFiUdp.cpp: In member function 'virtual int WiFiUDP::beginPacket(IPAddress, uint16_t)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\WiFiUdp.cpp:74: error: 'UDP_MODE' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\WiFiUdp.cpp: In member function 'virtual int WiFiUDP::endPacket()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\WiFiUdp.cpp:83: error: 'sendUdpData' is not a member of 'ServerDrv'
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\WiFiUdp.cpp: In member function 'virtual size_t WiFiUDP::write(const uint8_t*, size_t)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\WiFiUdp.cpp:93: error: 'insertDataBuf' is not a member of 'ServerDrv'
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\WiFiUdp.cpp: In member function 'virtual IPAddress WiFiUDP::remoteIP()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\WiFiUdp.cpp:149: error: 'getRemoteData' is not a member of 'WiFiDrv'
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\WiFiUdp.cpp: In member function 'virtual uint16_t WiFiUDP::remotePort()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\WiFiUdp.cpp:159: error: 'getRemoteData' is not a member of 'WiFiDrv'
```

Answer (score 1):

So I found out that my utility in my wifi library especially the server.cpp file wasnt the same as the updated github version. I just replaced my utilities and it worked fine. Thanks